# CSS3 slider, last image not showing up

Tags: html, css, slider

I am using an image slider, all is working fine, except when I edited the code to show an extra image (image id 6). All the animation works, and I can navigate to the 6th slide, but the image is black. When I inspect element it, it shows the imagepath is correct.

I also added the code in a fiddle with imageplaceholders, and there the 6th slide also shows a black box.

Any idea what I did wrong? I think it's something in the CSS but I cannot find what it is.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98LLpmc3/1/

My css code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    src: url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700);

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 1px;
}

h1 { color: white }

#slideshow-wrap {
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    min-width: 260px;
    max-width: 988px;
    margin: auto;
    /* border: 12px rgba(255,255,240,1) solid; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#slideshow-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner>ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -moz-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -o-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li {
    width: 20%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li>img {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):not(.show-description-label) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -45px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(200,200,200,1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s;
    transition: background-color .2s;
}

#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):active { bottom: -46px }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~label[for=button-1] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~label[for=button-2] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~label[for=button-3] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~label[for=button-4] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~label[for=button-5] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-6:checked~label[for=button-6] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-1] { margin-left: -36px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-2] { margin-left: -18px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-4] { margin-left: 18px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-5] { margin-left: 36px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-6] { margin-left: 54px }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: 0 }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -100% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -200% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -300% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -400% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-6:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -500% }

label.arrows {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(255,255,240);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

label.arrows:hover { opacity: 1 }

label.arrows:active { margin-top: -23px }

input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-4, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-5,
input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-6 {
    right: -55px;
    display: block;
}

input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4,
input[type=radio]#button-6:checked~.arrows#arrow-5 {
    left: -55px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1 { left: -19px }

input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2 { left: -37px }

input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-3 { left: -73px }

input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 { left: -145px }

input[type=radio]#button-6:checked~.arrows#arrow-5 { left: -289px }


.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
    z-index: 1000;
}

.description input { visibility: hidden }

.description label {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    background-color: rgba(255,255,240,1);
    position: relative;
    left: -17px;
    top: 00px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    z-index: 5;
    color: rgb(20,20,20);
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li:hover .description label { opacity: 1 }

.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~label { opacity: 1 }

.description .description-text {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,230,.5);
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: rgb(20,20,20);
}

.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~.description-text { opacity: 1 }
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow-wrap">
        <input type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="button-1"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="button-2" name="controls"/>
        <label for="button-2"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="button-3" name="controls"/>
        <label for="button-3"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="button-4" name="controls"/>
        <label for="button-4"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="button-5" name="controls"/>
        <label for="button-5"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="button-6" name="controls"/>
        <label for="button-6"></label>
        <label for="button-1" class="arrows" id="arrow-1">></label>
        <label for="button-2" class="arrows" id="arrow-2">></label>
        <label for="button-3" class="arrows" id="arrow-3">></label>
        <label for="button-4" class="arrows" id="arrow-4">></label>
        <label for="button-5" class="arrows" id="arrow-5">></label>
        <label for="button-6" class="arrows" id="arrow-6">></label>
        <div id="slideshow-inner">
            <ul>
                <li id="slide1">
                    <img src="images/slides/img1a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-1"/>
                        <label for="show-description-1" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Flower power</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="slide2">
                    <img src="images/slides/img2a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-2"/>
                        <label for="show-description-2" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Golden sunset</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="slide3">
                    <img src="images/slides/img3a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-3"/>
                        <label for="show-description-3" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Flower power again</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="slide4">
                    <img src="images/slides/img4a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-4"/>
                        <label for="show-description-4" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Stormy coast</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="slide5">
                    <img src="images/slides/img5a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5"/>
                        <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Splash!</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="slide6">
                    <img src="images/slides/img6a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-6"/>
                        <label for="show-description-6" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Splash!</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                 <li id="slide7">
                    <img src="images/slides/img7a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5"/>
                        <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Splash!</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                 <li id="slide8">
                    <img src="images/slides/img8a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5"/>
                        <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Splash!</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                 <li id="slide9">
                    <img src="images/slides/img9a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5"/>
                        <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Splash!</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                 <li id="slide10">
                    <img src="images/slides/img10a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5"/>
                        <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Splash!</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                 <li id="slide11">
                    <img src="images/slides/img11a.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5"/>
                        <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Splash!</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: if you think it's because of css then use http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator for validating the css. You'll know the errors and warnings.

Comment: I only got an @import related error, but that has nothing to do with the slides itself but with the font.

Comment: Are you sure about the image path?

Comment: Yeah, when I hover over the link in inspect element it shows the image. And I used imageplaceholder links in the fiddle, all the same link, but the 6th image doesn't show.

Comment: Your input ids are all the same from slide 7 to 11.

Comment: I know, but I only want slide 6 to work as of now, because I haven't edited the CSS for other slides yet. Originally the slide had 5 slides, I added a 6th and it shows a black box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the issue is with the CSS calculations. I guess initially there were 5 slides and based on that you had `ul` width as 500% and `li` width as 20%. But since now you have added another li, so the overall width and the individual width of li must change i.e 100/6 . And similarly, you should modify the margin-left property.

I hope you've got the answer.

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/98LLpmc3/11/

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow-wrap">
    <input type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked" />
    <label for="button-1"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-2" name="controls" />
    <label for="button-2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-3" name="controls" />
    <label for="button-3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-4" name="controls" />
    <label for="button-4"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-5" name="controls" />
    <label for="button-5"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="button-6" name="controls" />
    <label for="button-6"></label>
    <label for="button-1" class="arrows" id="arrow-1">></label>
    <label for="button-2" class="arrows" id="arrow-2">></label>
    <label for="button-3" class="arrows" id="arrow-3">></label>
    <label for="button-4" class="arrows" id="arrow-4">></label>
    <label for="button-5" class="arrows" id="arrow-5">></label>
    <label for="button-6" class="arrows" id="arrow-6">></label>
    <div id="slideshow-inner">
        <ul>
            <li id="slide1">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/988/400/sports/1/" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-1" />
                    <label for="show-description-1" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                         <h2>Flower power</h2>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="slide2">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/988/400/sports/2/" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-2" />
                    <label for="show-description-2" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                         <h2>Golden sunset</h2>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="slide3">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/988/400/sports/3/" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-3" />
                    <label for="show-description-3" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                         <h2>Flower power again</h2>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="slide4">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/988/400/sports/4/" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-4" />
                    <label for="show-description-4" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                         <h2>Stormy coast</h2>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="slide5">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/988/400/sports/5/" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5" />
                    <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                         <h2>Splash!</h2>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="slide6">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/988/400/sports/6/" />
                <div class="description">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-6" />
                    <label for="show-description-6" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                    <div class="description-text">
                         <h2>Splash!</h2>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400, 700);
 @font-face {
    font-family:'WebSymbolsRegular';
    src: url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    padding: 1px;
}
h1 {
    color: white
}
#slideshow-wrap {
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    min-width: 260px;
    max-width: 988px;
    margin: auto;
    /* border: 12px rgba(255,255,240,1) solid; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#slideshow-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#slideshow-inner>ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 600%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -moz-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -o-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
#slideshow-inner>ul>li {
    width: 16.66%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#slideshow-inner>ul>li>img {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):not(.show-description-label) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -45px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s;
    transition: background-color .2s;
}
#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):active {
    bottom: -46px
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~label[for=button-1] {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~label[for=button-2] {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~label[for=button-3] {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~label[for=button-4] {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~label[for=button-5] {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-6:checked~label[for=button-6] {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1)
}
#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-1] {
    margin-left: -36px
}
#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-2] {
    margin-left: -18px
}
#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-4] {
    margin-left: 18px
}
#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-5] {
    margin-left: 36px
}
#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-6] {
    margin-left: 54px
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
    left: 0
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
    left: -100%
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
    left: -200%
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
    left: -300%
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
    left: -400%
}
#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-6:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul {
    left: -500%
}
label.arrows {
    font-family:'WebSymbolsRegular';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 240);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
label.arrows:hover {
    opacity: 1
}
label.arrows:active {
    margin-top: -23px
}
input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-4, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-5, input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-6 {
    right: -55px;
    display: block;
}
input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4, input[type=radio]#button-6:checked~.arrows#arrow-5 {
    left: -55px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1 {
    left: -19px
}
input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2 {
    left: -37px
}
input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-3 {
    left: -55px
}
input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 {
    left: -73px
}
input[type=radio]#button-6:checked~.arrows#arrow-5 {
    left: -91px
}
.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px;
    font-family:'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
    z-index: 1000;
}
.description input {
    visibility: hidden
}
.description label {
    font-family:'WebSymbolsRegular';
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 240, 1);
    position: relative;
    left: -17px;
    top: 00px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    z-index: 5;
    color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
#slideshow-inner>ul>li:hover .description label {
    opacity: 1
}
.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~label {
    opacity: 1
}
.description .description-text {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 230, .5);
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~.description-text {
    opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track, I am not that good in CSS calculations, do you know what I need to edit the 500% in for it to show the 6th slide? I tried 600%, but that kinda breaks the slider, and shows half slides.

Comment: I updated the code but it still gives me a black box on slide6. Did you change anything else other than those two CSS properties?

Comment: Check the demo. I added sample images by replacing initial images. Also I moved the @import to the top. Let me share the full code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I copied the code and now it works, only the left arrow keeps moving to the left until it's out of the screen, any idea what causes it? Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Well, I am sure it must be due to calculations. Since the css contains lot of hardcoded values. Let me check.

Comment: Could you find anything?

Comment: Yeah, you need to change the left value of the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You missed to update the following CSS on adding the sixth slider.

```
#slideshow-inner>ul {
list-style: none;
height: 100%;
**width: 600%;**
```

You can refer this... http://jsfiddle.net/DDSridhar/bsvac0f1/2/
So on adding each new slide you need to update this too...